# Transit Mk7 Rear Hub won't go onto axle

Tags: ford, brakes, axle, hub, transit

I'm changing my rear brake discs and pads on my 2013 Transit Mk7. It's a FWD, SWB, 100T280.

I'm on the first wheel (left side rear), I've gone to put the hub back on with the new disc attached, it won't slide onto the axle completely, and now won't move forward or backward.

I've taken pictures of where the nut is at (with 200Nm of torque), as well as where the nut is at on the other side for reference (untouched by me).

What should I do? I don't want to just do the full torque in case something is wrong (400Nm or so.) The hub won't slide off either now, it is sort of jammed I suppose.

Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Can you add a photo zoomed out further to see the whole assembly, and one with a side view?

Answer (score 0):

After walking away for a while, I decided to use a hub puller (winding type, not slide hammer). Turns out the bearing had moved somehow in the hub, possibly due to the amount of chiseling/beating it took to seperate it from the old brake disc.

Pulling with the hub puller resulted in the bearing splitting, with one of the races still being left on the axle. The axle had been scored when the hub was reinstalled, this had created a lip which was preventing the hub from coming back off.

I then spent quite some time with varying grits of paper (40-600 grit) to get the axle smooth again. After this, the race came off, and I installed a new hub on the disc, and got this onto the axle successfully.

I hope this may be useful to someone someday. Quite the rookie error, but lessons were learnt, so the experience was worth it.

The lip I mention can be seen in the image below, as can the race which remained on the axle after the hub and disc were pulled off.

[image]